# Sorcerer spells that are useful in combat and performing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation

My backup character for my school's D&D club, who I'm actually planning on killing off my current character for, is a sorcerer who has a gimmick of dangerous or more commonly used for combat spells used to entertain others.

For example, (And I'm using Xanathar's guide too) her current spell list (very much open to suggestions) are Ray of frost, Shape water, Message, Dancing lights, Catapult, Magic Missile, Crown of Madness, and Enlarge/Reduce. What sorcerer spells should I have her learn that are useful in combat and performing?

Comment: So this question would only really be answerable for us if you could concretely define what you mean by "useful" and "performing". As it is, it just looks like you are asking for an open-ended list of suggestions and those questions do not work for this site's format and might be better asked [on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/42386).

Comment: Questions of the form "what options should I choose?" tend to get closed here for being too Opinion-based or too broad. A version of this question that might be answerable would be if you were to propose a specific spell list (without the open-ended "what should I add?" part) and ask for feedback on whether it's a good list or not; though even in that scenario you'd have to provide a lot of details about the campaign you're expecting to participate in. [You might be better off taking this question to a forum.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/42386)

Comment: @Xirema and on what you mean by "good" of course.

Comment: Also though, welcome to the RPG.se! Though this question may be on-hold, we still really appreciate your contribution and encourage you to stick around and contribute more!

Comment: Ah. I’m going to ask this on a forum like half the comments suggest. Sorry about that!

Comment: One possible suggestion for objective criteria to define spells useful in both combat and performing would be spells that have a combat effect (whether damage or otherwise) but which can also be directed into open space or otherwise cast in such a way as to look flashy without directly affecting anyone. For instance, *magic missile* fails this criterion, since the missiles *always* hit a target and deal damage to it.

Comment: @RyanThompson that's a good start, but there are probably too many spells that fit that criterion.